# modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_vs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1036-kvm

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

When I run command:

```
root@net-node01:~# modprobe ip_vs
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_vs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1036-kvm
```

I was install ipvsadm with command:
`apt install ipvsadm`

But when I run command `ipvsadm` thats return this error:

```
root@net-node01:~# ipvsadm
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_vs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1036-kvm
Can't initialize ipvs: Protocol not available
Are you sure that IP Virtual Server is built in the kernel or as module?
```

How can I fix this?

---

This another info with my machine:

```
root@net-node01:~# uname -a
Linux net-node01 5.4.0-1036-kvm #37-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 20:15:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
root@net-node01:~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-kvm`

Comment: @nobody linux-kvm was installed on my machine

Answer (score 3):

You seem to use `linux-kvm` as your kernel which is somewhat smaller and faster to start (for typical KVM guest use cases you don't need everything), but to achieve that it mostly disables some options and modules.
Therefore with `linux-kvm` as the kernel you won't have `ip_vs`.

If you instead use the generic kernel (more things enabled for general purpose use) there will be that module.

```
$ modinfo ip_vs
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-70-generic/kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs.ko
...
$ dpkg -S /lib/modules/5.4.0-70-generic/kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs.ko
linux-modules-5.4.0-70-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-70-generic/kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs.ko
```

Therefore switch to linux-generic and your case should work.

```
$ apt install linux-genric
# reboot into that kernel
```